# Swapping elements in a list in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to swap the elements of list `A` i.e. `(i,j)` turns to `(j,-i)`. But there is an error.

```
A=[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)]

for i in range(0,len(A)-1):
    for j in range(0,len(A)-1):
        A[i][j]=A[j][-i]
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    A[i][j]=A[j][-i]

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

The expected output is

```
[(0,0),(1,0),(0,-1),(-1,-1)]
```

Comment: tuple is immutable. You can't change its value. You have to create new tuple for that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is exactly as the error message says: the elements of a tuple cannot be replaced (assigned to). Instead, create a new tuple and replace the one that is currently in the list (since the elements of a *list* can be replaced.) I don't understand why you are confused, because the error message says exactly what is wrong, and because you did not **ask a question**. Please read [ask].

Comment: `A = [(j, -i) for i, j in A]`…?!

Comment: Moreover, there are some issues with your logic. You will get an index isuue

Comment: I think you are missing the syntax of swapping list values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a list of tuples, and tuples are immutable.  What you're doing would not be described so much as "swapping elements in a list" as swapping the elements of a tuple (and negating the second one).

If you have

```
a = (1, 1)
```

then you could perform this operation like:

```
b = (a[1], -a[0])
```

Performing that over a list of items a separate level of abstraction that can be handled in many different ways.  For example using a list comprehension:

```
A = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
B = [(a[1], -a[0]) for a in A]
```

or more simply using tuple unpacking:

```
B = [(j, -i) for i, j in A]
```

Comment: How does this return the expected output?

Comment: Is your `2nd` way inspired by @deceze?

Comment: @DanielHao Coincidence; I realized almost immediately that that's how I would do it in practice.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I don't understand your question.  How does it not?

Comment: probably the op made a mistake. The expected output is `[(0,0),(1,0),(0,-1),(-1,-1)]`, which is clearly different from what your algorithm returns

Comment: "i.e. (i,j) turns to (j,-i)"  it is clearly a mistake on the part of the OP.